# How many parallel universes exist in Futurama?

Tags: futurama, parallel-universe

In the first season, Fry is taken to and shown the edge of the universe, which looks onto a parallel universe. Fry turns to the Professor and asks, "Is there an infinite number of universes?," and the Professor responds, "No, only the 2."

However, later in "The Farnsworth Parabox" there appears to be an unlimited number of parallel universes, each contained in it's own box.

My question: how many universes exist in Futurama? Is there a set number or is there really an infinite number?

Please support your answers with quotes or links.

Comment: In *The Farnsworth Parabox*, the Professor's machine was making those boxes, and ergo making those other universes.

Comment: @Keen: That would mean that those other universes didn't exist before the professor "created them", but it seems that each of the other universes have their own history spanning longer than the few minutes it took to create them. It would make more sense to say that the boxes are doorways to the other universes. But this still means there are more than 2 universes...And doesn't answer my question.

Comment: If you created a universe in which matter and space are complex and highly organized (and the presence of living beings implies that), then there is no reason why the same cannot hold true for its time at the point of its creation.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the Professor is fallible.

Answer (score -2):

Just the two, and and I'm sure that's enough.

Comment: Any evidence to back this up besides the quote from the Professor in the first season?